# Django queryset filter by post variable

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am trying to do a queryset filter using Django. I have `Coupon` objects with a `code`, which is a `CharField`. I want to find all `Coupon` objects with a matching `code`.

My model:

```
class Coupon(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ... other fields
```

My view:

```
# This method returns the queryset
Coupon.objects.filter(code = "abc123")

# This part of the code is not working the way I want to
couponCode = str(request.POST.get("code"))
Coupon.objects.filter(code = couponCode)
```

I have ensured that the POST variable is `"abc123"` but I am still getting an empty queryset in the second query.

Comment: add `assert couponCode=='abc123'`

Comment: did you print `couponCode` and checked whats the value, or as above comment do an `assert` check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
couponCode = request.POST['code']
```

instead of

```
couponCode = str(request.POST.get("code"))
```

Comment: Do keep in mind that using request.POST['code'] will raise an exception if the key is not found. The safer option is request.POST.get("code"), as it will simply return None if the key isn't found.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `str()` part. Leave it only as:

`couponCode = request.POST.get("code")`,
then you could do:

`Coupon.objects.filter(code=couponCode)`

Hope this helps.